# Given a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $E,F \subset B$, prove $f^{-1}(E \cap F) = f^{-1}(E) \cap f^{-1}(F)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Given a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $E,F \subset B$, prove $f^{-1}(E \cap F) = f^{-1}(E) \cap f^{-1}(F)$

I want to see if I'm doing this correctly. The method of proving this is through the definition of image and preimage?

Def. Suppose $f : A \rightarrow B$

1. If $X \subseteq A$, the image of $X$ is the set $f(X) = \{f(x): x \in X\}\subseteq B$
2. If $Y \subseteq B$, the preimage of $Y$ is the set $f^{-1}(Y) = \{x \in A : f(x) \in Y\}$

Proof

$x \in (f^{-1}(E \cap F))$ consider $f^{-1}(E \cap F) = \{x\in A : f(x) \in E \cap F\}$
since $f(x)$ is in $E$ and in $F$ then $f^{-1}(E) \cap f^{-1}(F)$ $\rightarrow "\subseteq"$

$x \in (f^{-1}(E) \cap f^{-1}(F))$ consider $f^{-1}(E) = \{x \in A : f(x) \in E\}$ and $f^{-1}(F) = \{x \in A : f(x) \in F\}$ then $f(x) \in E \cap F$ from previous proof $f^{-1}(E \cap F)$. $\rightarrow "\subseteq"$

Comment: Ziggy, if $X \subseteq A$, the image of $X$ is the set $f(X) = \{f(x):x \in X\}\subseteq B\,.$

Comment: okay now i fixed it.

Comment: Instead of hackneyed confusing notations such as $\rightarrow"\subseteq"$, state what you actually mean. It is barely any harder, and it will be a lot cleaner: $f^{-1}(E\cap F) \subseteq f^{-1}(E) \cap f^{-1}(F)$ and $f^{-1}(E) \cap f^{-1}(F) \subseteq f^{-1}(E\cap F)$.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you.